# Add completion information for existing CLI utility?

Tags: powershell, tab-completion

For example, I would like to add completion to `adb` so that when I hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> after `adb` I can see sub-commands like `shell` and `install`. In Bash or Zsh the completion is always in separate file, so this is not an issue. How do I do similar thing in PowerShell (if ever possible)?

Comment: You can't.  PowerShell uses the IntelliSense engine.  You *could* create aliases, however

Answer (score 0):

Use [TabExpansion++](https://github.com/lzybkr/TabExpansionPlusPlus/).

There is precedent for using a script to generate completers for native commands (see [here](https://github.com/lzybkr/TabExpansionPlusPlus/blob/master/SupportTools/GenNetshCommandTree.ps1)).

(The comment about PowerShell using Intellisense is incorrect.)